# Is it possible to switch off or disable chat?

Tags: support, feature-request, chat

Sometimes on certain Stack Exchange sites I receive a chat request, usually by users that want to elaborate on my answer (even if it makes no sense IMHO).

I'm exclusively using the tablet app, so I just don't want to participate in chat and I don't want to see any chat requests either. It is even more annoying if the other user is in a different timezone. So there are chatrooms created for me and someone else which will not be used.

Is it possible to reject or ignore chat requests automatically? Or maybe block the possibility that a chatroom is created for me to participate in without my consent?

Comment: Just ignore it.

Comment: Haha a question tagged both "feature-request" and "chat". Good luck!

Comment: _without my consent_? Welcome to the internet!

Comment: I have a pretty long history on SO and I have no idea how to even open chat.

Comment: @canon Yes, I want to propose this as a new feature, but some users seem to think that the 'chat' tag is to be used in a more general way only, so the 'feature-request' tag has been removed by a user.

Comment: @canon I see what you mean... I've added the 'feature-request' tag once again. We'll see if it survives this time.

Comment: If it were possible, I'd want to be able to fake having chat disabled, so when someone asks me to help him in chat after the 13th time I tell him that I'm not interested in iteratively remotely debugging every problem with his app just because I answered his initial question, I could just pretend that I had the tablet flag on. (Just like "no, I'm not screening my calls, I must have just driven into a tunnel when you tried".)

Comment: Wait. You just have 8 answers on Stack Overflow. I wonder what Jon Skeet would be doing.

Comment: I imagine the [tag:feature-request] tag was removed because neither this question nor its title read in any way like a feature request?

Comment: @abarnert What are you suggesting?

Comment: @wie5Ooma: Sorry, I missed your comment because I was on my tablet and had comment notifications disabled. :)

Answer (score 34):

No, it's not.​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

Comment: bowing to the complexity of this one